# Prestashop 1.7 on save

Tags: api, prestashop-1.7

I need help, I don't know prestashop as well, I need to add an API call when I save a customer or an order, I could not figure out where to place the call.
Every help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a hook for do that some hooks is available for exemple when you want did something after save (update) an object you can use :

- actionObjectUpdateBefore

  or
- actionObjectUpdateBefore{objectName}UpdateBefore

Same thing for new add for object you have :

- actionObjectAddAfter
- actionObject{objectName}AddAfter

For more informations you have here a list of hooks in prestashop :

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/

In the code go at line 578 in the php file classes/ObjectModel.php for see the called hook

Comment: thank you very much, I look at it right away and update you